# jQuery hide <td>, but show <input>, that is in <td>

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have table. When I click on `<td>` in table, I want to see input field and hide td, but input is in `<td>`, so if i hide `<td>` i hide `<input>` too. Before this code, I use two `<td></td><td><input></td>` , and then everything was fine, but I need input in one `<td>`.

```
echo "<table>
<tr id='".$row['id']."'>
<td class='firstname'>".$row['firstname']."
<input type='text'  class='firstname' name='firstname' id='".$row['id']."' value='".$row['firstname']."'>
</td>
</tr>
<table>";
```

I try something like this in jQuery after click action, but it hide td and input too.

```
$("tr").filter("#" + rowid).find("td").filter("." + realclass).hide();
$("input").filter("." + realclass).filter("#" + rowid).show();
```

Those filters are good and everything else work fine. If I move hide() from td, then after click I see both - td and input.

Comment: So is the goal just that you want to hide the text in that column? Why not wrap the text in a span and hide the span? Also, element `id`s must be unique on a page.

Comment: I can add multiple classes?. Ok, try with span. I know, that code is strange, but i need both id and class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't hide parent element and leave child element visible. You can use some absolute positioning to make it look like input field is in td element.

Comment: That is last thing i want to do.. Mayble i can somehow move <td> text and see just input in this td?

Comment: You could put the text in some span element and hide the span element instead of td element